# How could I record the history of optaplanner solutions

Tags: java, optaplanner

Without extra configurations, optaplanner will return the best solution. But in my case, I need to have best n solutions. I see there is SolverEventListener which we can add to the solver, and the SolverEventListener has a method called bestSolutionChanged. We can listen on the events there. However, when I try doing that, it only catches two history records. I set the termination strategy as 10s limits. However, in debug logs, I do see it keeps moving after finding a best solution and it definitely logs the other best solutions with moves. But why in the event listener, it doesn't catch the newer solutions which are also best scores?

Besides, any suggestions on how I could record best n solutions? I see there sounds to be another hack with BestSolutionRecaller. Do you have an example how we could utilize BestSolutionRecaller?
Thanks!

I tried SolverEventListener suggested by the [wiki](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#SolverEventListener).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacking BestSolutionRecaller is the only way currently. BestSolutionEvents only report new, better solutions. Not better_or_equal solutions. This is a common feature request, [so I just created an issue](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/352).

---

If it's specifically **the Construction Heuristics best solution event that is missing** in the best solution event listener, this is a bug that as fixed in [Timefold Solver](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork) some time ago. In that case, try [a quick upgrade](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork#upgrade-from-optaplanner-to-timefold) to confirm the issue disappears.

Comment: Thanks @Geiffrey for the quick reply. I try upgrading to TimeFold Solver. The best events are still missing. We use FIRST_FIT for Construction Heuristics and get the logs:
Solving started: best score (-8init/0hard/0medium/0soft)

Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended:  best score (0hard/-1medium/0soft)
logs on Two events get logged with a better solution over the previous one.
Solving ended:  best score (0hard/0medium/0soft)

I think the issue should be BestSolutionEvents only report new, better solutions and we are not missing the Construction Heuristics best solution event

Comment: Do we have an instruction or example on how to hack BestSolutionRecaller? I see BestSolutionRecaller is a final field in AbstractSolver. We sound to override a lot of classes like AbstractSolver to hack? And besides, when could we expect the feature to be productionized? Thanks for raising the ticket! @Geoffrey De Smet

Comment: there are no guides on how to hack BestSolutionRecaller. It's not easy to do that properly from the outside...